# IBM CDC - Delta Change Monitoring

Tags: websphere, monitoring, cdc

Actually, I have a CDC working with AS400 source and writing to an AWS Kafka env.
Unfortunately, there are a number of tables with initial load successful but the Kafka target side (User) is complaining no data going to their side anymore.

I have checked with the AS400 with delivery to CDC and can't see any errors in the IIDR log.  I have opened the real-time statistic to check the pass-though.  There is nothing for those tables but there are traffics for others.

Is their any loggings with detailed delta loading records?  (rather than online monitoring in Management Console).  Thanks in advance

Willie

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by initial load here means 'refresh' , so when there is refresh is completed there will be messages in the event logs that will confirm. Please check in the source joblogs any messages logged during the time of refresh. Look out for any messages related to any authority related issue's logged in the joblogs. If still issue persists I would suggest to open a support ticket.

Thanks
Sudarshan K